# Toshiba laptop create weird plug in and out noises

Tags: toshiba-laptop, noise

My Toshiba laptop create this weird plug in and plug out noises when I plugged my phone's usb cord. This happens every time I plug my usb phone to my laptop, when I need something from my phone I need to turn off the sound so I could not hear those plug in and plug out noises. It's very disturbing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about custom sounds made by the manufacture, you can modify it in the themes.

To get to themes, right click on the desktop and click on Personalize.
From there, click on Sounds or Advanced Sound Settings.
There, you can either turn off sound effects, or change them to something else.

Comment: I am not talking about customs sounds made by the manufacturer I am talking about this plug in and out sound that my laptop create. When I plugged in my usb cord plug in and plug out continuously play even I do not plug out my usb cord.

Comment: If you are hearing the sound continuously, that means the device you connected (or some other device) is constantly disconnecting/reconnecting. Can you confirm if your device is not disconnecting and reconnecting continually?

Comment: or the possibility it's asking for more power than the USB port can supply it